# Function that returns struct item from a vector based on structs member data

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Im very new to c++ so I'm not very familiar with how lambda functions work here. I want to see if the vector 'problems' contains a struct item with a particular member value equal to 'animalProblemNumber'. I then want return the entire struct item. Below is the 'for-loop version' of what I'm trying to achieve.

I also have a function called 'checkProblem' to see if the 'Problem item' exists in the first place. Can I achieve both of these in the one function?

Thank you to who ever can help me.

```
Problem getProblem(int animalProblemNumber, std::vector<Problem>      problems){
for(Problem p: problems){
    if(p.treatment == animalProblemNumber){
        return p;
    }
}
```

}

```
bool checkProblem(int animalProblemNumber, std::vector<Problem> problems){    //change this to lambda 
for(Problem p: problems){
    if(p.treatment == animalProblemNumber){
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: Don't overanalyse it. Pass stuff around naturally and if you are really worried, look at the assembly. I think you'll find that pretty comforting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The return type of `getProblem()` will be a problem, no pun intended, if the `vector` does not contain at least one matching item. It will be better to return an iterator.
2. Change the input to `getProblem()` a `const&` so that the retured iterator is valid when the function returns.
3. After that, you can use `getProblem()` to implement `checkProblem()`.j
4. `checkProblem()` can also be changed to accept a `const&` although it is strictly not necessary.

```
std::vector<Problem>::const_iterator getProblem(int animalProblemNumber,
                                                std::vector<Problem> const& problems)
{
    return std::find_if(problems.begin(), problems.end(),
                        [animalProblemNumber](Problem const& item)
                        { return item.treatment == animalProblemNumber; });
}
```

and

```
bool checkProblem(int animalProblemNumber, std::vector<Problem> const& problems)
{
   return (getProblem(animalProblemNumber, problems) != problems.end());
}
```